# Leer una cadena con scanf( ) incluyendo espacios

Tags: c

Estoy atascado en esto ya que no se como resolverlo, tengo un programa que introduciendo una cadena, debería imprimir solo las vocales, para esto solo puedo usar `stdlib` y nada de referencias a los arrays, solo punteros. ¿Como es posible?
Mi código hasta el momento:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char cadena[20];

main() 
{
    int longitud(char *);
    char *p;
    p=cadena;
    printf("Ingrese una cadena con longitud maxima de 19 caracteres:\n");
    scanf("%s",p);
    int x=longitud(p);  
    while (x>20){printf("El texto escrito supera los 19 caracteres, ingrese otra cadena:\n");scanf("%s",p);x=longitud(p);}
    int count = 0;
    for(p;(*p) != '\0'; p++){if (*p == 'a' || *p == 'e' || *p == 'i'|| *p == 'o' || *p == 'u'|| *p == 'A' ||*p == 'E' ||*p == 'I' ||*p == 'O' ||*p == 'U')count++;}
    printf("La cantidad de caracteres de su cadena es de %d.\n", x);
    printf("Su tweet contiene %d vocales.\n", count);

}

int longitud(char *p){
    int c=0;
    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        c++;
        *p++;
    }
    return(c);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es tu pregunta exactamente? _"¿Cómo es posible?"_ no es una pregunta válida.. ¿cómo se responde a eso? ¿a qué te refieres?

Answer (score 1):

Ya que mencionas que sólo puedes usar `<stdlib.h>` y punteros te recomendaría que no usaras [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) y usaras [`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

[`fgets`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) es una mejor manera de leer datos que scanf.

Su firma es la siguiente:

```
char * fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

Como dice la función lee como máximo "*size* - 1" caracteres o hasta un salto de línea (**\n**) o un **EOF**.

Esto evita que guardes más elementos de los que tu arreglo en realidad es capaz de leer.

Solamente que deberías especificar como archivo que se leerá de `stdin`

Algo así:

```
char cadena[20];
fgets(cadena, 20, stdin);
```

De una vez te menciono que no es necesario hacer esta parte de tu código puesto que realmente estás duplicando el valor que guarda cadena (un puntero a la primera posición de memoria de tu arreglo)

```
char *p;
p=cadena;
```

Comment: *Esto evita que guardes más elementos de los que tu arreglo en realidad es capaz de leer, cosa que sucede con scanf...* En realidad, a [scanf](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) se le puede especificar el tamaño del búfer para evitar el posible desbordamiento.

Answer (score 0):

En tu scanf quita el "flag" `%s` y pon `%[^\n]`. De esta forma te toma la cadena con los espacios incluidos.

Comment: Por favor explica qué significa `%[^\n]` y señala el nuevo carácter que le indicará a scanf que ahí termina la entrada

Comment: Hay que especificar el tamaño del búfer para evitar posible buffer overflow: `%19[^\n]`